# why is this bash code so slow in comparison to corresponding cpp code?

Tags: c++, bash, performance, performance-testing

I am new to OS as it was introduced to us very recently.
we have bash code to run as our lap experiments.
my last task was to code a program to print whether a number is prime or not.
i coded it first in cpp because i am comfortable in cpp. and then coded same in bash after lot of googling. but my bash code is very slower than the cpp code.

I wrote a cpp code to check whether a number is prime or not.
cpp code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isprime(int a) {
    if (a == 2 || a == 3)
        return true;
    if (a % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    if (a % 3 == 0)
        return false;
    for (int i = 1; (6 * i - 1) * (6 * i - i) <= a; ++i) {
        if (a % (6 * i - 1) == 0)
            return false;
        if (a % (6 * i + 1) == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << ((isprime(n)) ? "Prime" : "Not Prime") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote the same code in bash (linux):

```sh
read num
f=1
if test $num -eq 2
  then f=1
elif test $num -eq 3
  then f=1
elif  test `expr $num % 2` -eq 0
  then f=0
elif test `expr $num % 3` -eq 0
  then f=0
else
  for (( i=1; $((`expr i\*6-1`))**2 <= num; i++))
  do
    t=`expr $i \* 6 - 1`
    if test `expr $num % $t` -eq 0
    then
      f=0
    fi
    t=`expr $i \* 6 + 1`
    if test `expr $num % $t` -eq 0
    then
      f=0
    fi
  done
fi

if test $f -eq 1
then
  echo 'Prime'
else
  echo 'Not-Prime'
fi
```

but cpp code is very fast and bash code is very slow
here is terminal input and output

```
a@a:~/Cp$ cat > input
1000000007
^?^C
a@a:~/Cp$ time ./a.out < input
Prime

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.000s
a@a:~/Cp$ time ./prog.sh <input
^C
real    0m8.258s
user    0m5.906s
sys 0m2.794s
a@a:~/Cp$ # I interrupted the execution.
```

I have no idea why is this happening?

Comment: Not sure what you expected here, you're comparing C++ (a compiled language) against Bash (an interpreted language that uses tons of subprocesses for basic things). Of course C++ will be faster.

Comment: please check also the for loop, it could be stay for infinite time in the for loop if the condition is not written well. I suggest you to check the consition separately.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as pointed above nature of bash make any complex calculation slow.

Comment: bash becomes a bit faster if you don't call `expr` (subshell) and use bash internal mathematics instead.

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh : Inside the loop body of your bash version, you are creating 4 child processes (in each iteration!). If you would do this from C++, it would be slow too.

Comment: @user1934428 how can i reduce that?, i had reduced that to 2 after the optimisation mentioned by Wiimm and that made a huge difference.

Comment: Do not use backticks, use `$(..)` instead. And do not use `expr`. Ever. Forget it exists. Just `if ((num % t == 0)); then` etc.

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh : I don't understand in your script, why you sometimes use bash arithmetic to calculate the integer expressions `$((...))`, and sometimes and sometimes create a child process running `expr`. I would simply do everything inside bash.

Comment: within the C++ loop you effectively 'break' out of processing if either of the `% == 0` tests are met, whereas in the bash loop no such break is made; for non-prime numbers you may be able to save some cycles by breaking out of the bash `for` loop once you set `f=0`

Comment: @markp-fuso, yes i forgot that :sweat_smile:, but that was not going to make any differnce for the input i was trying.

Answer (score 3):

**The C++ as other compiled languages have for sure a better performance with respect to interpreted languages like bash, sh, python**.

This because when you use a compiled program, only a process is launched, while when you run an interpreted program it instatiates a great number of subprocesses also for basic operation.

So is trivial that c++ program is faster than the bash one.

Comment: Thankyou i didn't knew that.
I was curious because even python is giving instant output. and bash is taking like forever.

Comment: if is forever probably the condition of the for loop is not written well. Check it before says this.

Comment: the code is working for small inputs.

it is giving instang output upto N <= 10^5. after that it goes slow.

Comment: ok so it's a problem of performace, probably memory consuption. Try to run top command to monitoring the operation

Comment: thankyou,
ok i am working on that, as i mentioned i am new to os, i'd have to google how to use top command to monitor tha operation.

Comment: an interpreted program not necessarily spawns subprocesses. Also it is not C++ as a language that has better performance, it is the resulting executables that often perform better. C++ can be interpreted too

Comment: thankyou @ZigRazor i could see using top, the above code was not using much memory but was slow from the reason you mentioned. some one told me to check expr command with basit mathematical statements and this was a huge optimisation. and now code is running under a second. for N ~= 10^10.

Answer (score 3):

There's not much to the code other than tests and math, but you are spending a lot of time on those individual bash-level commands.

We can eliminate the overhead of the bash-level command/process calls by pushing all of the code down into a single `awk` call.

Here's a verbose copy of your bash code running in `awk`:

```
$ cat isprime
#!/usr/bin/bash
input=${1}                                                 # user's input number;
                                                           # OP will probably want to add some logic to validate the input as numeric

awk -v num="${input}" '                                    # pass input number to awk in 'num' variable
BEGIN { f=1 }                                              # init our flag
      {        if (  num      == 2 ) { f=1 }
          else if (  num      == 3 ) { f=1 }
          else if ( (num % 2) == 0 ) { f=0 }
          else if ( (num % 3) == 0 ) { f=0 }
          else for ( i=1 ; (i*6-1)**2 <= num ; i++ ) {
                   t=(i*6-1)
                   if ( (num % t) == 0 ) { f=0 ; break }   # for non-prime numbers we can abort the for loop to save some cycles
                   t=(i*6+1)
                   if ( (num % t) == 0 ) { f=0 ; break }   # for non-prime numbers we can abort the for loop to save some cycles
               }
      }
END { msg="Prime"
      if ( f == 0 ) { msg="Not-Prime" }
      print msg                                            # print our finding to stdout
    }
' <<< ""                                                   # awk needs a 'file' to work on so we'll feed it an empty here-string
```

Timing this script for the sample number '1000000007` gives us:

```
$ time ./isprime 1000000007
Prime

real    0m0.262s
user    0m0.061s
sys     0m0.170s
```

**NOTE**: Repeated runs of the above test showed real run times ranging from **0m0.082s** to **0m0.262s**; the wide range of numbers is due to me running the above under `cygwin` in a Windows7 VM; I would expect more consistent run times (towards the lower end?) in a linux environment; ymmv ...

And a non-prime test:

```
$ time ./isprime 1000000006
Not-Prime

real    0m0.125s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.045s
```

Not as fast as the C++ program but definitely a good bit faster than processing all those individual bash-level test/process calls.

There are a few `awk`isms that could be added to shave some additional time off the run but for the sake of this answer I wanted to make it as easy as possible to compare the code with the OPs C++/shell code snippets.

---

The usefulness of this `awk` solution will be based on the size of the input (number).

Testing the above against some [20-24 digit primes](https://primes.utm.edu/curios/index.php?start=20&stop=24) shows this `awk` solution immediately bails on the `%2==0` or `%3==0` tests. This comes down to numerical limits in a basic `awk` implementation.

From my man pages for `awk`:

```
-M
--bignum
    Force arbitrary precision arithmetic on numbers. This option has no effect if gawk is  not  compiled  to
    use the GNU MPFR and GMP libraries.  (In such a case, gawk issues a warning.)
```

Adding the `-M` flag to the above `awk` solution does allow the script to work on a 21-digit prime, but it's not fast ...

```
awk -M -v num="${input}" ' ...

# and then:

$ time ./isprime 998887766553300224411
... as I type this it's going on 8 minutess of 100% cpu utilization (total of a single core)
... aborted after 13 minutes
```

While I have no doubt this `awk` solution would eventually complete, the basic fact is it's going to take a looooong time to count from `1` to a `21-digit number` by increments of `1` (`i++`) (this will be true for any implementation whether it be `bash`, `awk`, `C++`, etc).

For really large numbers I'd be looking at other (much more complex) algorithms for verifying a number is a prime.

Comment: Re-writing the whole thing in awk is quite a large work. Add to that the additional analysis and I would request everybody to upvote this answer!

Comment: it is not working in 82 ms, it is working in 17ms. i am shocked thankyou. i got a lot to learn.

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh that's good to hear; I know my cygwin/VM env is slow but didn't realize it's **that** slow! :-)

Comment: updated to `break` out of the `for` loop if we find a non-prime (ie, we set `f=0`) since there's no reason to continue testing additional `i` values at this point

Answer (score 3):

This is a much faster bash version

```
read num
f=1
if test $num -eq 2 -o $num -eq 3
  then f=1
elif  (( num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0 ))
  then f=0
else
  for (( i=1; ; i++)); do
    t=$((i * 6 - 1))
    (( t * t > num )) && break
    (( num % t == 0 || num % (i * 6 + 1) == 0 )) && { f=0; break; }
  done
fi

if test $f -eq 1; then
  echo 'Prime'
else
  echo 'Not-Prime'
fi
```

All calls to `expr` have been removed.

```
time bash test.sh <<< 1000000007
Prime

real    0m0.128s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.094s
```